# What it means $\lim_{|x|\rightarrow+\infty}u(x)=0$?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

If $u\in W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ is a solution of a pde problem , what it means $$\lim_{|x|\rightarrow+\infty}u(x)=0$$

Comment: It usually means that the sequence $\sup\{|u(x)|\mid \|x\|>n\}$ converges to zero.

Comment: @Vrouvrou: Just for curiosity, is there any relation given between $p$ and $N$?

Comment: @s.harp: The trouble is that $u$ is not a function (with pointwise values), but an element of $L^p$, so it doesn't make sens to speak of $u(x)$. That's why I use the *essential* supremum in my answer, and not just the (usual) supremum.

Comment: @AlexM. $p<N$ that is the relation

Answer (score 1):

One posible interpretation is the following: for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exist a compact $K_\epsilon \subset \Bbb R ^N$ such that $\text{ess sup} \left| u \big|_{\Bbb R^N \setminus K_\epsilon} \right| < \epsilon$, where $\text{ess sup}$ is [the essential supremum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_supremum_and_essential_infimum).

Comment: and what we can deduce for this solution ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou: Sorry, your question is quite vague, can you be more precise please?

Comment: We win what when we have this property? What is its importance?

Comment: @Vrouvrou: Usually, when you search for solutions in a space of functions that "vanish at the boundary" (and in this case the boundary is $\infty$), *sometimes* you get uniqueness, which is a very nice property - but this depends on the equation under consideration.